# libcurl post username and password

Tags: c++, curl, post, libcurl

I think I have read every libcurl post related question on stackoverflow, yet I still can not seem to get my login code to work.  I have copied code from other sample post programs as well as code from https://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078
and it still doesn't work.  There are no errors in the code itself, however the final get keeps redirecting to https://www.masteringbiology.com/site/notloggedin.html.
I am trying to login and use the cookies to access a specific page on the site.
I am 100% self taught and would appreciate help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl\curl.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
CURLcode res;
// string URL= "https://session.masteringbiology.com/myct/assignmentPrintViewassignmentID=6607103";
CURL* curly= curl_easy_init();
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
if(curly){
    cout<<"go!!!"<<endl;
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://www.masteringbiology.com/site/login.html");
curl_easy_perform( curly );
// Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_REFERER, 
"https://www.masteringbiology.com/site/login.html");
// Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
char *data="nme=xxx&pwd=yyy";
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_perform( curly );

//todoc
curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
   //curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://session.masteringbiology.com/myct/mastering#/");
    FILE * filename1;
filename1=fopen("filetest.txt","w+");
if(filename1) {
// write the page body to this file handle
 curl_easy_setopt(curly, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, filename1);

// get it!
res=curl_easy_perform(curly);

// close the header file
fclose(filename1);
}

if (res==CURLE_OK){
cout<<"Yeah!!!";
}
else{cout<<"oh no!!! "<<res;}
}
else{
    fprintf(stderr, "curl initialization failure");
return 0;
    }
curl_easy_cleanup(curly);
return 0;
}
```

Here is the html for the login form

```
 <!-- Mastering hidden form -->
            <form name="hiddenForm" id="hiddenForm" class="hidden" 
method="POST" action="https://session.masteringbiology.com/login" 
target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" id="authProvider" name="authProvider" 
value="SMS" />
                <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="" 
/>
                <input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" value="" 
/>
                <input type="hidden" id="passwordEncType" name="passwordEncType" value="" />
            </form>
            <!-- end Mastering hidden form -->
            <form class="form-stacked has-validation" name="loginForm" 
id="loginForm" method="post" action="#" target="_top" autocomplete="off" 
data-errorMsg="Please supply the information for all required fields marked 
below.">
                <label for="nme">Username</label>
                <div class="group nowrap">
                    <input type="text" name="nme" id="nme" class="medium-
width required-field">
                </div>
                <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                <div class="group nowrap">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" 
class="medium-width password required-field">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="button button-big-icon bg-
color-match uppercase mar-top-x1Half">
                <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00f;" class="left">
</span>Sign In</button>
```

Comment: Why are you performing a `POST` request to retrieve the login HTML? You should be performing a `GET` request instead. You need to use `POST` only when sending the webform data.

Comment: It automatically switches to get.

Comment: You are explicitly setting `CURLOPT_POST=1` for a request that should be using `GET` instead. Even if curl implicitly switches to `GET` internally, setting `CURLOPT_POST` for a non-`POST` request is wrong. On the actual post, setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` implies `CURLOPT_POST=1` (the documentation says so). So, I would just omit the explicit `CURLOPT_POST` altogether.

Comment: In any case, I suggest you login to the site using a webbrowser and sniff its HTTP traffic. You will see there is much more going on during the login process than your code is accounting for (you are submitting the wrong input fields to the wrong URL). Also, the correct URL of the login HTML page is `https://www.masteringbiology.com/site/login.html`, not `https://www.masteringbiology.com/site/login` that your code is using.

Comment: What are the correct input fields?

Comment: If you sniff a webbrowser's traffic during a real login, like I suggested, you would see it sends input like this: `cmd=login`, `encPassword=Y`, `errurl=https://auth.mastering.pearsoncmg.com/mxauth/authProvider/SMS/loginSSOFail/101807eafe991efbba47bfc117b96be7`, `isCourseAware=N`, `loginname=<username>`, `okurl=https://auth.mastering.pearsoncmg.com/mxauth/authProvider/SMS/loginSSOPass/101807eafe991efbba47bfc117b96be7`, `password=<hashed password>`, `siteid=6689` to this URL: `https://login.pearsoncmg.com/sso/SSOServlet2`. The HTML does not show that, so a script is likely altering the form

Comment: Ohhh I understand, ok I will try that. Thank you.